# Retrieve Encrypted data from the JSONStore in IBM MobileFirst

Tags: encryption, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I have created a JSONStore and trying to encrypt the data inside the collection.
My understanding is that AES encryption is done by securing the collection with a username and password; I successfully did that by setting  `localKeyGen : true`.

However I am still getting the plain text as the response.

**JSONStore**

```
 var collectionName = 'people';

// Object that defines all the collections.
var collections = {

  // Object that defines the 'people' collection.
  people : {

    // Object that defines the Search Fields for the 'people' collection.
    searchFields : {name: 'string', age: 'integer'}
  }
};

// Optional options object.
var options = {

  // Optional username, default 'jsonstore'.
  username : 'carlos',

  // Optional password, default no password.
  password : '123',

  // Optional local key generation flag, default false.
  localKeyGen : true
};

WL.JSONStore.init(collections, options)

.then(function () {

  // Data to add, you probably want to get
  // this data from a network call (e.g. Worklight Adapter).
  var data = [{name: 'carlos', age: 10}];

  // Optional options for add.
  var addOptions = {

    // Mark data as dirty (true = yes, false = no), default true.
    markDirty: true
  };

  // Get an accessor to the people collection and add data.
  return WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).add(data, addOptions);
})

.then(function (numberOfDocumentsAdded) {
  // Add was successful.
})

.fail(function (errorObject) {
   // Handle failure for any of the previous JSONStore operations (init, add).
});
```

**Response**

```
{"collection":{"name":"people","username":"carlos","searchFields":{"name":"string","age":"integer","_id":"number"},"additionalSearchFields":{},"promise":{}},"docs":[{"_id":1,"json":{"age":10,"name":"carlos"}}]}
```

How can i retrieve the encrypted data? if the encryption is already happening by securing the collection with a username and password.

References

- [Link 1](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_init.html)
- [Link 2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_sec_utils_overview.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encryption is meant only to prevent access to the JSONStore.

By .init-ing it with the username and password, this means you have successfully accessed it and you are thus able to see the collection inside it.

Had the .init failed, you would not be able at all to retrieve the data to begin with.

Comment: Does that means that the security mechanism is limited up to securing the JSONStore by Username and Password. Can't we encrypt the data inside these store by AES. One more query , is the encryption happening in the first place , over the password also , and is it making use of the SQLCipher already included in the IBMWorklight Toolkit ?

Comment: The collection, the data, is encrypted.

Comment: ok , can we view the encrypted collection / data , by any means ?

Comment: Can you help me out with my previous query @IdanAdar